# Why is ./filename required to run executable script?

Tags: bash, osx, chmod

After creating a Python script file, test.py, in my home directory, and running `chmod +x test.py` to make it executable, and placing `#!usr/bin/env` as the file header, I expected to be able to run the script from `bash` on OS X, using:

```
$ test.py
```

but `bash` returned:

```
-bash: test.py: command not found
```

The following command worked:

```
$ ./test.py
```

Why is the relative path required for this executable script in the present working directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell searches the execute path ($PATH) for programs when you give it a command to run.  Pre-fixing a command with a path, such as ./ prevents the shell from searching and instructs the shell to use a specific program, explicitly specified.

If a program resides in a directory not in the search path then you have to explicitly indicate the path to the program.